# Two criterias and single regex for generic postal code

Tags: regex, postal-code

I created a regex for postal code (non us countries) to include two criterias ..

- minimum 5 chars , max 10 chars
- should have only alpha numneric with only one space/hyphen in the middle

regex: ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,10}[ |-]{0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,7})(.{5,10})$

I'm not sure where this is going wrong, but this is not working

Comment: Show some examples that should pass and some that shouldn't.

Comment: 12A31-A43 , 123-A1a15, 12345-ASD, NP-12345, NP 12345, 1235 234, ultimately it is alphanumeric which is atleast 5 character length, and atmost 10, may have one of either space or hyphen in the middle, number of characters before or after space/hyphen is not important

Comment: i could only make one of the criterias work separately but not in the combined regex as given in my post

Comment: Maybe something like `^(?=[^- ]*[- ][^- ]*$)[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d -]{4,9}[A-Za-z\d]$`

Comment: @CAustin Thanks Austin, this works well with one space/hyphen in middle. but if space/hyphen is removed then it's not working

Comment: @CAustin i tweaked your solution a bit, ^(?=.{5,10}$)(?=[^- ]*[- ]{0,1}[^- ]*$)[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d -]{4,9}[A-Za-z\d]$ ... this is working in a scenario where no space/hyphen is required. Thanks again

Comment: @AbhishekKakkerla If you put `{0,1}` after the `[- ]`, it will allow patterns that do not contain any space or hyphen in the middle. Not sure if that was your intention. If so, note that `{0,1}` is synonymous with simply writing `?`.

Comment: yes @CAustin, i was also thinking of this scenario too to include in my requirements.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
(?=^\w+[ -]\w+$)^[a-zA-Z0-9 -]{5,10}$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/xqMq7o/2

Breakdown:

- `^[a-zA-Z0-9 -]{5,10}$` sets the pattern for the allowed chars and size. It could be alone if it wasn't for the space/hyphen requirement
- `(?=^\w+[ -]\w+$)` makes sure there's at least and at most one space/hyphen. (`\w` is OK to use because it includes `a-zA-Z0-9` but not `-`. Alternatively, `[^ -]` could be used in its place.)

Comment: this works great, and thanks for the explanations gives more clarity

Comment: Okay, glad the explanation helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

after reading the posts from @acdcjunior and @CAustin, I corrected my solution too based on the regex they provided ...

(?=^.{5,10})^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,10}[ |-]{0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,7}$

this has more criteria than what i initially posted ...
1. limit a minimum of 3 to the left of space/hyphen which not mandatory
2. limit a maximum of 7 to the right of space/hyphen
3. overall the length should be 5 to 10
4. should be alphanumeric

hope this helps to someone else too.

Thank again.